# Error when converting git repo to mercurial using hg convert

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

If I run:

```
hg convert /path/to/repo
```

I get the error:

```
abort: invalid mode ('r') or filename
```

I've checked and I think the error is a Python error, but it doesn't help me resolve the errror.

Is there any way to get more information and, ultimate fix?

Comment: "way to get more information" is to show real output of command with --traceback option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bug, introduced in 2.1.1](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3311)

Downgrade to 2.1 or wait April release: patch already committed.

Comment: FYI - TortoiseHG just release v2.4 which comes bundled with HG 2.2.1 which fixes the problem